# How can I change the color hyperlinks in WIX for ADDITIONAL INFO SECTIONS in a product page?

Tags: velo

I utilize the ADDITIONAL INFO SECTIONS in my product page layout.  One of the sections is labelled "Compatibility."  I've hyperlinked text, but the hyperlink text is very light grey and barely readable when it renders.  How can I get this linked text to be a more readable color?

Here's a l[ink to the product page](https://www.liftaway.com.au/product-page/liftaway-lauvr1-universal-garage-door-remote) I'm working on:

Comment: Talked to WIX support staff.  This issue was reported as an enhancement request.  For now,  I will move the links into the description. (font colour is supported in this field.)

Answer (score -1):

I managed to do it today.
Edit your hyperlink at description section and then copy to the additional info.
Right now only first line works. When you try it, you will know what im talking about when you doing it :P

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.